# How to deploy react js project with changeable domain?

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-router, web-deployment, appdomain

I found myself in a bit of a problem with deploying a react js project. I've been developing qr code restaurant menu app for a while now. It is supposed to work as it follows: I've created an app in Android Studio and XCode from where users can edit their menus (users with authorization), and I've finished the react js app which is supposed to be only for reading menus. Now I am interested in whether is it possible to host a project so that it has a normal fix part of domain(first page) but at the end something like "/somekindofid" because I am using react router dom for navigation in the project and it works when I start it locally, like first page that it is opening is http://localhost:3001/... -> those three dots are some kind of id, because when I scan qr code it will contain some kind of url where at the end is some kind of unique id, and based on that id it will approach database and load the menu.

```
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './app.css';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Categories from './pages/Categories';
import Meals from './pages/Meals';
import MealDetails from './pages/MealDetails';
import About from './pages/About';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:restaurantId" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/categories/:restaurantId/:language" element={<Categories />} />
        <Route path="/about/:restaurantId" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/meals/:restaurantId/:id/:language" element={<Meals />} />
        <Route path="/mealdetails/:restaurantId/:categoryId/:mealId/:language" element={<MealDetails />} />
      </Routes>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my App.js and as you can see first page is the domain plus restaurant id. My question is can I deploy this project somehow that last part of domain is changeable (restaurantId in my case).

I tried to deploy it on netlify and i don't really get how it should work. When I manually try to type the route of a certain page in the URL section I got 404 error, but when i manually type path of a certain page locally after localhost:3000 it works. For example: https://myapp.netlify.app/hAdsaSV65asdAdKMs
where https://myapp.netlify.app is supposed to be domain while hAdsaSV65asdAdKMs is supposed to be restaurant id. Than I would read it using useParams(). Does anybody knows a possible solution to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok never mind, I found a solution in using hash router and than putting /#/ in domain as a separator of url and restaurant ID.